# How to get products not from the current category in category page?

Tags: event-observer, collection, filter

I have Sales page as category.

I am using observer (`catalog_Product_Collection_Load_Before`) to filter products which to be shown in frontend.

But I am getting only products connected to the current category (Sales).

How to modify collection to get other products, not related with current category?

Comment: Why can't you just add products to this category?

Comment: Actualy it helped. But in this case i need  to control this option  automatily with some script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the little hack in magentos libs.

There is possibility to use setPart for Select object

https://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Db/Varien_Db_Select.html#setPart

Answer (score 1):

Good point by SeStro.

Beside this: You only get products you filter for. The collection filters for products in the category, therefore you only get them. To remove the filter, you have either to manipulate the select directly or call `$collection->reset()`

But both are bad ideas, because you don't know the side effects.

So back to the suggestion by SeStro: You have a category, put products into you want to have for sale